How to identify binary registered as login-items in macOS Sonoma System Settings/General/"Open in Background"?
Today an application named "Galvanix" was registered on my macOS Sonoma 14.5.
When it happened, I just noticed a notification and opened the macOS System Settings/General/"Open in Background" and saw "Galvanix" listed.
At first I did not know what requested it, and disabled it. I searched my disk for that string and found that the macOS build of Emacs has been built by someone that has the 'Galvanix' developer ID.

Question: Is there a way to identify the path of the binaries registered as login-items shown in this System Settings/General/"Open in Background" dialog?

Is this stored inside some text file somewhere?  Or is there a command line tool that I can use to see the entries that are shown in the System Settings/General/"Open in Background"?



Update:  As described in https://emacsformacosx.com/tips at the end of the page, "Galvanix" is the Developper ID of the author of the Emacs for Mac OSX package.

Did you recently install Emacs (text editor)?

@red_menace ,I did install emacs before and more instance today.  I think the report is from the macOS build of Emacs, as I ran sysdiagnose and found 'Glavanix' to be the dev ID related to that version of Emacs.  I updated my question accordingly.  I'd like to find a way simpler that sysdiagnose to get to the list of binaries though.

It looks like it uses a launcher so that it can run several different binaries from the application bundle.

That's the case; it supports binaries for emacs, emacsclient, ctags, and etags for various CPU architectures.  I'm still trying to launch an Emacs daemon where the emacsclient runs in graphics mode, but that's another story...

@red_menace Which version and where did you get this Emacs from. I have used emacs before but not seen this issue.

@mmmmmm I can't say for red_menace, but for me its with Emacs 29.3 I got from Homebrew --cask when I tried to to activate the abaility to launch the emacs daemon by writing a plist for it inside ~/Library/LaunchAgents.  I was learning that and did not realize that 1) simply writing the file was activating it right away and 2) the word 'Galvanize' was taken from the Emacs.app file bundle.  In retrospect, it's making sense, but I wish the Systems/Settings/General/Open in Background dialog at least identified the path of the binary it activates or had a way to identify it.

@mmmmmm - I haven't used Emacs, but have seen a developer name in the login items instead of an app name for a background process, so I took a look to see if that might be what was happening.  I found an Emacs 29.3 build by the developer Galvanix at https://emacsformacos.com, which looked like a possibility for where the name was coming from.

The is no single method of discovering what all the items in System Settings/General/"Open in Background" dialog relate to, let alone finding the binary or plist which launches them.
There are a number of ways identifying the product:

The name or icon of the "application".
Using launchctl list and sudo launchctl list.

The output may help identify the product. For example, the first non-obvious application in my list is labelled "Andreas Hegenberg". I used sudo launchctl list| grep hagen and launchctl list| grep hagen.  This was lucky, the output included application.com.hegenberg.BetterTouchTool. Now I know the product - BetterTouchTool.
For the second application labelled "Bryan Christanson", I tried searching for both Bryan and Christiansen in the launchctl output. But nothing.

The most reliable way is a web search.

I used DuckDuckGo searching for "bryan christianson macOS". The results made it very likely what what I was looking for is "WhatRoute" app which I have on my Mac.
With your "Galvanix", I searched for "galvanix macos" Three of the first six results referred to Emacs.
So, even if the launchctl method does not give you any hints for "Galvanix", the web search would get you there.
Having identified the product, now to find the binary which launches them. This binary will be specified somewhere in a plist on your system.
You can search use an app like Find Any File for a plist with a name that relates to your product or developer.  In your case a name with either "emacs" or "galvanix". The plist will include the command to run the binary  or whatever it does.
For my examples, this identified the plist and the binary. For one of them the plist was in /Library/LaunchDaemons (one of the obvious places to look), but the other was in the application package. But in both cases I could get to the associated binary.
Much of the searching is simplified using an app like Lingon X, which allows you to skip the launchctl commands and makes searching for the plist easier and displays its content. But doesn't help when you need to use a web search to identify the application!

Apart from Lingon - there is also Launch Control(https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) which I switched to.

@mmmmmm I have both. Do much the same thing but, right now, I prefer the presentation and searching of Lingon.  They both seem to have a really decent nice person as developer.
